# How to override styles of md-input-container in angular2?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I have the following piece of code for **md-input-container** using angular material design:

```
<md-input-container>
      <input mdInput [placeholder]="'common.password' | translate" type="password" formControlName="password" (change)="onPasswordChange($event.target.value)" required validate-onBlur/>
      <md-hint *ngIf="frmLoginInfo.controls.password.pristine" class="s-text-caption s-hint">{{ 'signup.pwdRule' | translate }}</md-hint>
</md-input-container>
```

This container has a div inside with class (mat-input-wrapper) which has a padding of **padding-bottom: 1.296875em.**

**How do I override this padding style of the container?**

PS : Adding class to the container and making the padding: 0px as **important** also doesnt work.

[image]

Comment: `.mat-input-wrapper {  padding-bottom: 0px !important;}` should work

Comment: yes @sTx although that will change **all** instances of `.mat-input-wrapper` to have 0 padding

Comment: so you should add an  `id` or `class` for a parent element, just like @0mpurdy said in his answer and target like `#parent > .mat-input-wrapper{....}`

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Official Response from Angular about `/deep/` or `>>>` ([Thanks @DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446896/6894075))

> Support for the emulated /deep/ CSS Selector (the Shadow-Piercing descendant combinator aka >>>) has been deprecated to match browser implementations and Chrome’s intent to remove. ::ng-deep has been added to provide a temporary workaround for developers currently using this feature.

From: http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/angular-43-now-available.html

[Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445533/how-to-style-ng-bootstrap-alternative-to-deep/45446896#45446896)

---

Add a more specific style to the component - [see CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

**html**

```html
<md-input-container id="forceStyle">
    <input mdInput [placeholder]="'common.password' | translate" type="password" formControlName="password" (change)="onPasswordChange($event.target.value)" required validate-onBlur/>
    <md-hint *ngIf="frmLoginInfo.controls.password.pristine" class="s-text-caption s-hint">{{ 'signup.pwdRule' | translate }}</md-hint>
</md-input-container>
```

**css**

```css
>>> #forceStyle .mat-input-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You need the `>>>` as explained [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1276)

However `/deep/` and `>>>` are deprecated as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

[image]

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DmK45PwSyzKYOsSZQpHr?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesnt work either..After inspecting the element on chrome developer tool,I am not able to see the styles applied.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal - this example  should work with a little change: `#forceStyle.mat-input-wrapper ` - after I've seen your screen

Comment: I've updated the answer with a fix and a live demo example, although be aware that `/deep/` is being deprecated - see alternatives in the GitHub issue I linked.

Comment: I think there is no need for `deep`, just a more specific target

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal - make sure u clear cache, even serve the app again because sometimes changes are not loaded

Comment: How do I use /deep/ in my code? its giving error. SHould I change something in HTML too?

Comment: just add it in front of the style, don't forget the space between it and the ID - you can see an example in the plunker link I posted

Comment: I am using scss and it gives me error saying at rule or selector expected

Comment: Looks like you're having [this issue](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/452) use `>>>` instead of `/deep/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="box-model"> 
       <md-input-container fxFlex="auto" class="custom-search-mdinput">
         <input mdInput [placeholder]="'common.password' | translate" type="password" formControlName="password" (change)="onPasswordChange($event.target.value)" required validate-onBlur/>
         <md-hint *ngIf="frmLoginInfo.controls.password.pristine" class="s-text-caption s-hint">{{ 'signup.pwdRule' | translate }}</md-hint>
        </md-input-container>
</div>

@Component({
    selector: "dashboard",
    templateUrl: "dashboard.component.html",
    styles: [`.box-model .mat-input-wrapper {
        margin: 0px !important;
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    }`
    ],
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149978/discussion-between-vignesh-and-shruti-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <md-input-container>
     <input mdInput [placeholder]="'common.password' | translate" type="password" formControlName="password" (change)="onPasswordChange($event.target.value)" required validate-onBlur/>
      <md-hint *ngIf="frmLoginInfo.controls.password.pristine" class="s-text-caption s-hint">{{ 'signup.pwdRule' | translate }}</md-hint>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper .mat-input-wrapper{padding-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

**Important** `.mat-input-wrapper` need to be a child of `wrapper` - from your example I don't know where that class come from

---

After your post update I think it should work the following:
`#forceStyle > .mat-input-wrapper{padding-bottom: 0 !important}` - should work even without the `important` but just to be sure.

**Make sure you clear cache and even relaunch the app because sometimes changes are not loaded**

Comment: I cleared the cache and relaunched the app too. Didnt work.

Comment: That's so strange....can you give a style to `#forceStyle` a margin, border, anything and check if you can see it in inspect?

Comment: Yes I added border to it and it gets added.

Comment: now try `#forceStyle > div{padding-bottom: 0 !important}`

Comment: This style is not getting applied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149975/discussion-between-stx-and-shruti-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Use deep for styling

```
/deep/ .mat-input-wrapper { 
  padding-bottom: 0px ;
}
```