# How to replace Angular Material Styles on own?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I try to changes CSS styles in style.css of components file like this:

```css
.mat-tab-label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

But it does not repalce Angular Material styles. 
Any custom style can not overwrite Angular Material styles.

Comment: make important..

Comment: I also does not work, I think it is hook,not right way

Comment: You want to override material css using your own css correct..

Comment: I think you are using Component CSS file. Use a separate CSS file and include at the end of head tag.

Comment: I write styles in component CSS file: `styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']`

Comment: It may be something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45274656/6894075) where you need `/deep/` or `>>>` but be aware that browser support for this is not universal

Comment: how you defined your button in html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding `/deep/` before the css class:

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

**OR**

```
>>> .mat-tab-label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

`/deep/` and `>>>` will be depreciated soon. So use the new `::ng-deep` ([Details Here](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459))

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.2), 0 -3px 4px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.12), 0 -2px 4px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.14);
}
```

Comment: Does not work: `/deep/ .mat-tab-label-active {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #3e4eb8;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.2), 0 -3px 4px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.12), 0 -2px 4px 0 rgba(62, 78, 184, 0.14);
}`

Comment: Where are you putting that? Should be in your `./dashboard.component.css`

Comment: `/deep/` is deprecated, wont support in future versions.

Comment: @Daniel, if it helped then please mark the answer as accepted so that someone else can benefit as well if they face a similar issue

Comment: As a note, all 3 are deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Angular Material styles because of the specific order of styles in your html. Thus, Angular puts your style.css first, before any Angular components' styles (including Angular Material). Hence, there are few ways to design Angular Material components:

1. Use the `!important` tag in your stylesheet.
2. Create a new component which inherits the angular-material component with a new `@Component` decorator to define new styles (in this case, you don't import the Angular Material component module at all).
3. Change the order of styles in your html. You can either manually put your custom Angular Material styles after the `<body>` tag or reconfigure WebPack to include your styles.css after the `<body>` tag.

   As for the third option, to reconfigure WebPack:

   a. Add ngx-build-plus: `ng add ngx-build-plus`

   b. create a file ng-plugin.ts:

   ```
   export default {
     pre() {
     },
     config(cfg) {
       const util = require('util');
       for (const rule of cfg.module.rules) {
         if ('include' in rule && rule.use[0] === 'style-loader') {
           rule.use[0] = { loader: 'style-loader', options: { insertInto: 'body' } };
         };
       }
       return cfg;
     },
     post() {
     }
   };
   ```

   c. Compile the file: `tsc ng-plugin.ts`

   d. Add to angular.json

   ```
   "serve": {
     ...
     "options": {
       ...
       "plugin": "~ng-plugin"
     }
   }
   ```

PS: Unfortunately it only works in the development configuration, and I don't now how to setup the production configuration accordingly. So, in the production, I have to put  the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.2c8b1779b4d75bca36df.css">` after the `<body>` tag manually.

Answer (score -2):

Encapsulated styles (the default for a component) will affect direct children of a component, but since `.mat-tab-label` is a child of the tab component, your styles cannot affect it.

You should do one of the following:

1. Turn off encapsulation on your component: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
2. Add overriding styles to a global stylesheet `.my-tabs .mat-tab-label { }`
3. Use deprecating shadow piercing in your component stylesheet such as `& ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label { }`

Also, material component styles are loaded when the component is instantiated and will often come *after* your overriding styles, thus taking precedence. Be sure to make your selector a little more specific.

Comment: I did that, but I must to set `!important` for properties.

Comment: Did you make your selector more specific, as mentioned in the final paragraph? Also see https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6087

Comment: `!important` should never be required, and every element can be styled without it, as long as your styles are not encapsulated and are more specific than the material selectors